# laravel Whoops, looks like something went wrong

Tags: laravel-5

laravel, I click the search button so there is an error message "Whoops, looks like Something went wrong."

```
public function kategori(Request $request)
    {

      $keyword = $request['keyword'];

      $kota = $request['city'];

      $City= City::where('nameCity','<>',$kota)->get();
      $Kate=Category::where('categoryType',$keyword)->get();


      // $branch = Branch::where('branchName','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")->paginate(30);
      $branch = DB::table('mi_branch')->join('mi_resto_category', function ($join) use ($kota,$keyword)
       {
        $join->where('categoryType', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
       $join->on('mi_branch.branchCategory', '=', 'mi_resto_category.categoryId');})
      ->where('branchVenue','=',"{$kota}")->orWhere('branchAddress','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
      ->where('branchVenue','=',"{$kota}")->orWhere('branchName','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
      ->where('branchVenue','=',"{$kota}")->orWhere('branchPointRules','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
      ->where('branchVenue',"{$kota}")->get();

return view('v_bykategori',compact(['brand'],['branch'],['kota'],['City'],['Kate'],['keyword']));
```

[image]

Comment: You need to specify more your error.

Comment: You are returning so many variables in compact method, it's not a problem but you can do it like `$data['brand'], $data['branch']` and then return only `$data` variable to view. And in view you can access it in the same way, like `$data['branch']` etc, Another thing why are you using `[]` in compact method ? you can simply pass variables with compact('brand','branch','kota'); etc.....